# Errors When Creating A Column Which Is The Difference Between Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if I have a dataframe and I want to create a new column of the same dataframe whose result is row-wise result is column1 - column 2, what is the best code to accomplish this?  column1 and column2 have NaNs in them so I believe that's why I'm getting errors.

THanks,
Ben

Here is my dataframe

```
>>> frame2
   col1  col2  col3
0   NaN   NaN     8
1     2     5     9
2   NaN   NaN    10
3     4     7    11
4   NaN   NaN    12
```

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please post raw data for both dfs, your code to create the dfs and the desired result, note that lots of reasons exist for why this didn't work such as incompatible shape, different index values, different column names etc.

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that the `dtypes` are either `str` or have mixed types so can you please for the love of [blazing saddles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNC3OciAF3w) post raw data, code to load that data that reproduces the error

Comment: What are the dtypes of your columns? That error pretty clearly suggests you're trying to subtract strings.

Comment: Figured it out.  sorry relax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To subtract, say, `col1` and `col2`, try `astype(float):

```
df.col1.astype(float) - df.col2.astype(float)
```

Your columns look like numbers, but they are actually strings, according to the message.